# Change size of whole set of elements

Tags: boxes, include

I am trying to include some gnuplot-generated figures using the epslatex terminal, which creates an .eps file and a .tex file. The way to include these figures in the document is writing

```
\include{./figure}
```

These files include all the commands that set the tics, the legend and so on. My question is: is it possible to **change the size** of **the whole set** of elements included in `figure.tex` *without modifying* that file?

Something like this:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{figure}
    \include{./presion_posicion2}
    \caption{Diagrama presión-posición para el ensayo 2}
    \label{fig:ensayo2}
\end{figure}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `\input` instead of `\include` and the other way round with `\resizebox`:

```
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{./presion_posicion2}}
    \caption{Diagrama presión-posición para el ensayo 2}
    \label{fig:ensayo2}
\end{figure}
```

You can everything define inside the figure environment, it will be valid for the code of `\input`

Comment: @Herbert, which one do you prefer `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` ?

Comment: @xport: `\scalebox` only when I have a lot of images and want all scale down by the same factor and no one is wider than `\linewidth`. When I need some images as wide as the linewidth or part of it, then `\resizebox` is the better choice.

Comment: @Herbert, thank you for this tip of the day.

Comment: @Herbert, may I also ask why should be \input instead? I read this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include/250#250 but I didn't see the point

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer. It worked!

Comment: @Juanlu001: `\include` starts with a new page, which is useful for chapters in books and has its own auxiliary file. It also cannot be nested. `\input` can be used in the preamble and elsewhere and be nested because it does nothing else then replacing itself with the code of the given file name.